# Why isn't my spring boot repository recognizied as bean

Tags: spring-boot

My little app is supposed to be a cinema magement bakcend.
I would like to use an In-Memory H2 database in order to register and other ops on ticket reservations.

**Reservation** Entity

```
package fr.univlyon1.m2tiw.tiw1.metier;
...

@Entity
public class Reservation {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column
  private Long id;

  @Column
  private String prenom;

  @Column
  private String nom;

  @Column
  private String email;

  @Column
  private boolean paye;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String seanceId;

  public Reservation() {
  }
  ...
```

**The repository**

```
@Repository
public interface SpringJPAReservationDAO extends CrudRepository<Reservation, Long> {
  List<Reservation> getBySeanceId(String seanceId);

  Reservation getByEmail(String email);

  Reservation getByEmailAndSeanceId(String email, String seanceId);
}
```

**SpringBoot Run**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableJpaRepositories("fr.univlyon1.m2tiw.tiw1.dao")
@EntityScan("fr.univlyon1.m2tiw.tiw1.metier")
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, BeansException, ClassNotFoundException {
     SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

**Application properties**

```
# Control the ThymeleafViewResolver:
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html

# DataSource properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:mytestdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

**Run logs**

```
/pping service [Tomcat]
2018-11-27 11:47:30.763  INFO 8811 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-11-27 11:47:30.949 ERROR 8811 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adminController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'serveur'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serveurImpl' defined in file [/home/francois/projects/m2/2018/is/tpspring2018/metier-base/target/classes/fr/univlyon1/m2tiw/tiw1/serveur/ServeurImpl.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [fr.univlyon1.m2tiw.tiw1.serveur.ServeurImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'containerChild' defined in fr.univlyon1.m2tiw.tiw1.config.SpringConfig: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'containerChild' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'fr.univlyon1.m2tiw.tiw1.dao.SpringJPAReservationDAO' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at fr.univlyon1.m2tiw.tiw1.Application.main(Application.java:23) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serveurImpl' defined in file [/home/francois/projects/m2/2018/is/tpspring2018/metier-base/target/classes/fr/univlyon1/m2tiw/tiw1/serveur/ServeurImpl.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [fr.univlyon1.m2tiw.tiw1.serveur.ServeurImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'containerChild' defined in fr.univlyon1.m2tiw.tiw1.config.SpringConfig: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'containerChild' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'fr.univlyon1.m2tiw.tiw1.dao.SpringJPAReservationDAO' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1164) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1239) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1166) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [fr.univlyon1.m2tiw.tiw1.serveur.ServeurImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'containerChild' defined in fr.univlyon1.m2tiw.tiw1.config.SpringConfig: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'containerChild' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'fr.univlyon1.m2tiw.tiw1.dao.SpringJPAReservationDAO' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:184) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1262) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'containerChild' defined in fr.univlyon1.m2tiw.tiw1.config.SpringConfig: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'containerChild' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'fr.univlyon1.m2tiw.tiw1.dao.SpringJPAReservationDAO' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:767) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:508) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:88) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at fr.univlyon1.m2tiw.tiw1.serveur.ServeurImpl.<init>(ServeurImpl.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'fr.univlyon1.m2tiw.tiw1.dao.SpringJPAReservationDAO' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1646) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1205) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1166) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:855) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:758) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 56 common frames omitted

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:40993', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It seems like the repository is recognized as a bean, at least in intelij.
I cannot locate the problem.

**pom.xml**
Some of the dependancies are used by other classes inside the app. I don't think there is any problem with them but who knows

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>fr.univlyon1.tiw.tiw1</groupId>
        <artifactId>base</artifactId>
        <version>2018</version>
        <relativePath>..</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>metier-base</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Comment: What's `SpringJPAReservationDAO` package?

Comment: Please mention where the `Application` class is defined.

Comment: It is not the reository, the exception said : 'adminController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'serveur', means in your AdminConroller you have a dependency of Serveur. is that right? if is true so is Serveur class a spring component ? if yes try to add @ComponentScann in your main class and put inside the package of your Serveur component

Comment: SpringJPAReservationDAO package is *fr.univlyon1.m2tiw.tiw1.dao*

Comment: The *Application* class is in the root package

[fr.univlyon1.m2tiw.tiw1]

Comment: I should have given more info, my bad.
adminController **uses** serveur which **uses** containerChild which **uses** springJPAReservationDAO which **uses** reservation

Comment: add logging.level.org.springframework.beans=debug to your application.properties to show details of bean creation in the log. It might shed some light - what you have posted looks like it should work. Also check the SpringJPAReservationDAO.class is in the jar

Comment: I did as you @pcoates said but have same logs

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

I actually had a SpringConfig file with declared beans.

**SpringConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig 
{
    @Bean
    public JSONCinemaDAO jsonCinemaDAO() throws IOException{
        return new JSONCinemaDAO();
    }

    @Bean
    public SalleDAOImpl  salleDAOImpl(JSONCinemaDAO cinemaDAO) throws IOException{
        return new SalleDAOImpl(cinemaDAO);
    }

    @Bean
    public ProgrammationDAOImpl programmationDAOImpl(SalleDAOImpl salleDAO,JSONCinemaDAO cinemaDAO)
            throws IOException, ParseException{
        return new ProgrammationDAOImpl(salleDAO,cinemaDAO);
    }

    @Bean
    public SeanceManager seanceManager(ProgrammationDAOImpl p_DAO, SpringJPAReservationDAO r_DAO) throws IOException, ParseException{
        return new SeanceManager(p_DAO,r_DAO);
    }

    @Bean
    public CinemaRessourceFilms cinemaRessourceFilms(ProgrammationDAOImpl p_DAO,SpringJPAReservationDAO r_DAO,
                                                     SeanceManager child) throws IOException, ParseException{
        return new CinemaRessourceFilms(p_DAO,r_DAO,child);
    }

    @Bean
    public CinemaRessourceReservations cinemaRessourceReservations(ProgrammationDAOImpl p_DAO,SpringJPAReservationDAO r_DAO,
                                                                   SeanceManager child) throws IOException, ParseException{
        return new CinemaRessourceReservations(p_DAO, r_DAO, child);
    }

    @Bean
    public CinemaRessourceSalles cinemaRessourceSalles(ProgrammationDAOImpl p_DAO, SpringJPAReservationDAO r_DAO, SeanceManager child,
                                                       SalleDAOImpl salleDAO) throws IOException, ParseException{
        return new CinemaRessourceSalles(p_DAO,r_DAO,child, salleDAO);
    }

    @Bean
    public CinemaRessourceSeances cinemaRessourceSeances(ProgrammationDAOImpl p_DAO,SpringJPAReservationDAO r_DAO,
                                                         SeanceManager child) throws IOException, ParseException{
        return new CinemaRessourceSeances(p_DAO,r_DAO,child);
    }
}
```

I just removed it and added **@Component** or **@Service** annotation to classes according to their roles